# Transpose range in excel with VBS

Tags: vbscript, excel.application

Hey guys need some help here . how can I transpose a range in excel with VBS? basically copy a range from one sheet then pastespecial transpose on the other sheet. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub transpose()
           Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: thx for the fast answer ill let you know if it works, but is that for VBS or VBA ?

Comment: I think that it should work with VBS, but let me know if you have any problems. 

You may want to directly reference the excel files as objects, which would require you to dim the excel application and reference the file location. I'm going to update my post to include this.

Comment: Hey dude thanks,so it turns out it didn't work in vbs but it needed to be translated into what wscript would understand will post what I used to test Thanks again :D @cronos2546

Answer (score 1):

```
 Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CuRrY\Desktop\test1.xls")
 objXLApp.Application.Visible = True
 objXLApp.DisplayAlerts=False
 Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Sheets(1)  

 objXLWs.Range("A1:O1").Copy
 objXLWs.Range("A2").PasteSpecial ,,,True
```

from what I have seen in other scripts I wrote,wscript goes through the entire string
so just added the commas and just put the transpose part as true >>>

```
.Range("A2").PasteSpecial ,,,True
```

Thanks again cronos2546 , I love this site :)